# Idea behind $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq\mathsf{P}/\mathsf{Poly}\implies\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ not true?

Tags: complexity-theory

$\mathsf{3SAT}$ in $n$ variables is an $\mathsf{NP}$ complete problem.

Augment input to $\mathsf{3SAT}$ with constants $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{n^c}$ where each constant $|a_i|<n^e$ to get an artificial problem ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$. There is a direct reduction from $\mathsf{3SAT}$ to ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$.

Assume that $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq \mathsf{P}/\mathsf{Poly}$ where suppose there exists $n^c$ constants for a fixed $c$ that will help solve any $n$-variate $\mathsf{3SAT}$ instance in $n^d$ time for a fixed $d$, however finding those constants offline takes exponential amount of time.

Since by hypothesis of $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq \mathsf{P}/\mathsf{Poly}$, we have constants that help solve $\mathsf{3SAT}$ in poly time, let augmented input to ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$ contain constants that help solve ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$ in poly time.

**${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$ is $\mathsf{NP}-\mathsf{complete}$:** $\mbox{  }$ Since $\mathsf{3SAT}$ reduces to ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$, ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$ problem remain $\mathsf{NP}-\mathsf{complete}$.

**${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$ is in $\mathsf{P}$:** $\mbox{  }$ Follows from hypothesis of $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq \mathsf{P}/\mathsf{Poly}$.

So why then is still $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq\mathsf{P}/\mathsf{Poly}\implies\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ not true?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to augment $\Pi$ with constants? What do you mean by "let augmented input [...] contain these constants"? Why can you just assume/claim that the input contains those constants?

Comment: Why does "$\hat{\Pi}$ is in P" follow "from hypothesis of $\:$NP $\subseteq$ P/poly$\:$" $\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: because of constants chosen. see sdcvcc answer below.

Comment: @RickyDemer **Please** stop manually spacing your answers and comments. They look unreadably terrible on everybody's screen but yours.

Comment: Please define the problem $\overline{\mathsf{3SAT}}$. And please use some other notation for it: over-line normally denotes complement, so $\overline{\mathsf{3SAT}}$ normally denotes the set of unsatisfiable 3CNF formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since $\mathsf{3SAT}$ reduces to ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$, ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$ problem remain $\mathsf{NP}-\mathsf{complete}$.

The "reduction" isn't a polynomial time one. To create an input for ${\mathsf{3SAT}}_{aug}$ you need to compute the constants $\{a_i\}$ which takes exponential time.

Answer (score 6):

Assume $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq \mathsf{P}/\mathsf{Poly}$. Let $\Pi$ be a NP-complete problem, by assumption, this problem can be solved by some circuit family. It is true that the problem $\hat{\Pi}$ where the input is a pair consisting of input to $\Pi$ and a circuit making an appropriate computation, is in $\mathsf{P}$. However, from this fact you cannot conclude that the original problem $\Pi$ is in $\mathsf{P}$. To obtain a solution to $\Pi$ using $\hat{\Pi}$ you have to guess the circuit - and this is not a priori possible in $\mathsf{P}$. You could guess the circuit nondeterministically, but then the argument would prove that $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{NP}$. However, if you start with a $\Sigma_2$ set instead, it is possible to fix this reasoning and obtain $\Sigma_2=\Pi_2$ ([Karp-Lipton theorem](http://Assume%20$%5Cmathsf%7BNP%7D%5Csubseteq%20%5Cmathsf%7BP%7D/%5Cmathsf%7BPoly%7D$.%20Let%20$%5CPi$%20be%20a%20NP-complete%20problem,%20by%20assumption,%20this%20problem%20can%20be%20solved%20by%20some%20circuit%20family.%20It%20is%20true%20that%20the%20problem%20$%5Chat%7B%5CPi%7D$%20where%20the%20input%20is%20a%20pair%20consisting%20of%20input%20to%20$%5CPi$%20and%20a%20circuit%20making%20an%20appropriate%20computation,%20is%20in%20$%5Cmathsf%7BP%7D$.%20However,%20from%20this%20fact%20you%20cannot%20conclude%20that%20the%20original%20problem%20$%5CPi$%20is%20in%20$%5Cmathsf%7BP%7D$.%20To%20obtain%20a%20solution%20to%20$%5CPi$%20you%20have%20to%20guess%20the%20circuit%20-%20and%20this%20is%20not%20a%20priori%20possible%20in%20$%5Cmathsf%7BP%7D$.%20You%20could%20guess%20the%20circuit%20nondeterministically,%20but%20then%20the%20argument%20would%20prove%20that%20$%5Cmathsf%7BNP%7D%20=%20%5Cmathsf%7BNP%7D$.%20However,%20if%20you%20start%20with%20a%20$%5CSigma_2$%20set%20instead,%20it%20is%20possible%20to%20fix%20this%20reasoning%20and%20obtain%20$%5CSigma_2=%5CPi_2$%20(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%E2%80%93Lipton_theorem).)).

Comment: Since $\mathsf{3SAT}$ reduces to $\Pi$ which reduces to $\hat{\Pi}$, doesn't $\hat{\Pi}$ problem remain $\mathsf{NP}-\mathsf{complete}$? By definition $\hat{\Pi}\in\mathsf{NP}$, while since $\mathsf{3SAT}$ reduces to $\hat{\Pi}$ every problem in $\mathsf{NP}$ reduces to $\mathsf{3SAT}$ $\implies$ every problem in $\mathsf{NP}$ reduces to $\hat{\Pi}$.